# Is there a way to store values of loop in a dataframe into another column in same dataframe?

Tags: python

Need to generate new column in df which have output stored corresponding to variables like this:

[Output required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjQg1.png)

```
import pandas as pd
#create simple dataframe
x=1
y=2
data = {'var': ['print(x)', 'print(y)']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
#print values
n=0
while n<len(df['var']):
    exec(df['var'].iloc[n])
    n=n+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `exec` for this is a terrible idea... far better would be using a dictionary and the map function:

```
import pandas as pd
vars = {
   'x': 1,
   'y': 2,
}
data = {'var': vars.keys()}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output:

  var
0   x
1   y
```

Now, we can create your new column easily:

```
df['new_col'] = df['var'].map(vars)
print(df)

# Output:

  var  new_col
0   x        1
1   y        2
```

---

---

---

If you absolutely insist on using your `exec`-like method... you could do this. Assuming they're all just print statements:

```
df['new_col'] = df['var'].str[6:-1].map(lambda v: eval(v))
print(df)

# Output:

        var  new_col
0  print(x)        1
1  print(y)        2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are better approaches you must to consider before. This kind of code is difficult to maintain and any thing can break it up easily.

```
# factory decorator
def factory_1(**kwargs):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(text_func):
            func = function
            result = func(text_func, **kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator

# The variables goes here!
@ factory_1(x=1, y=2)
def function(functext, **kwargs):
    
    # This function assumes that every variable exists
    # You can put a Try-Except block two put a default value
 
    lambda_func = 'func = lambda ' 
    for key in kwargs:
        lambda_func += key+ ', '
    lambda_func += ': '
    
    lambda_func += functext + '\n'
   
    
    result = 'solution = func('
    variables = str()
    for key in kwargs:
        variables +=  f'{key} = {kwargs[key]}, '
    result += variables + ')'
    
    result = lambda_func + result
    local = dict()
    exec(result, local)
    return local['solution']


df=pd.DataFrame({'var': ['print(x)', 'print(y)']})
```

But remember that in your example you used `print` function and this return `None` and send the output to `std output` by default. So will print the output but the exit will be None in conclusión in the table will we a column of `none` values. But this function works with short phrases as lambda functions becuse I used lambda functions to pass the `var` column to it.

**Note** the variables goes in the decorator

[image]

if you decide to put onother function like `x+1` and `y+5` in the `var` column the output will be:

[image]